# Getting error method not allowed and content-type:text/plain

Tags: http, go, post, postman

All my routes are working perfectly except `CreateGoal`. Whenever I add data using the `Post` method it is giving me the message `method not allowed`.When I checked the `Get` method Headers Content-type, it is **application/json** but when I checked the `Post` method Headers Content-type, it is **text/plain; charset=utf-8**. So I think there must be a problem with Content-type. I am not understanding how to solve this problem. I have attached the screenshots for reference.
Screenshots:[image]
[image]

Routes:

```
func Setup(app *fiber.App) {

    app.Get("/goals", controllers.GetGoals)
    app.Get("/goals/:id", controllers.GetGoal)
    app.Post("/goals/add", controllers.CreateGoal)
    app.Put("/goals/:id", controllers.UpdateGoal)
    app.Delete("/goals/:id", controllers.DeleteGoal)

}
```

Controllers:

```
import (
    "strconv"
    "github.com/gofiber/fiber/v2"
)

type Goal struct {
  Id        int    `json:"id"`
  Title     string `json:"title"`
  Status        bool   `json:"status"`
}

var goals = []*Goal{
    {
        Id:        1,
        Title:     "Read about Promises",
        Status:         true,
    },
    {
        Id:        2,
        Title:     "Read about Closures",
        Status:         false,
    },
}

func GetGoals(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
    return c.Status(fiber.StatusOK).JSON(
    // "success":  true,
    // "data": fiber.Map{
            // "goals": goals,
        // },
        goals,
  )
}

func CreateGoal(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
    type Request struct {
        Title string `json:"title"`
    }

    var body Request
    err := c.BodyParser(&body)
    if err != nil {
        return c.Status(fiber.StatusBadRequest).JSON(fiber.Map{
            "success": false,
            "message": "Cannot parse JSON",
            "error":   err,
        })
    }

    goal := &Goal{
        Id:        len(goals) + 1,
        Title:     body.Title,
        Status: false,
    }

    goals = append(goals, goal)

    return c.Status(fiber.StatusCreated).JSON(fiber.Map{
        "success": true,
        "data": fiber.Map{
            "goal": goal,
        },
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your endpoint is `/goals/add` in the application for `POST` method. But in Postman you called `/goals`

In application `/goals` expecting a `GET` request. That is why there method is not allowing.